# Delphi 10.4 with xCode 10.1 (12.1 SDK) - how to ensure it can support wide range of iOS versions out there?

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi

Environment:

- Delphi 10.4
- XCode 10.1 in MacOS High Sierra (highest version due to hardware constraint)
- iOS 12.1 SDK

Test iPhone:

- iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 13.6

preferably hope to support version 9.x to 14.x

Comment: A bit broad of a question as there a multiple issues to look at in supporting old versions of iOS and devices. An old article but still useful in highlighting the various issues: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2668-supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices

Comment: You need to use at least Xcode 11 with iOS 13 SDK to submit apps to the App Store, even if you support older iOS versions for execution

Comment: In Delphi, using XCode 11, and if I stick only to basic widgets common to 10 and 11, would that mean I would support iOS 10,11,12,13,14 automatically, or is there more work than this to configure in Delphi?